# can a player always have a pure best response strategy?

Tags: game-theory

I have a general simple question.
Does a player always have a pure best response strategy in response to mixed strategies of other players in all kinds of games?

Comment: It need not be unique.

Comment: Define pure best.

Comment: @orlp pure strategy best response and not a mixed one;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there are (infinite) games where no best response (either pure or mixed) exists. See f.i. the standard example of a Bertrand duopoly with symmetric costs and continuous prices.

If a best response exists, it may not be unique. However, if the best response is a mixed strategy $\sigma$, it is necessary that the player is indifferent among all the pure strategy in the support of $\sigma$. Therefore, if a best response exists, there must be at least one that is also a pure strategy.